# Convergence $\int_{-\infty}^{1} {\left|x^n\right| e^x dx}$ by using the comparison test

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm wondering if it's possible to study the convergence of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{1} {\left|x^n\right| e^x dx}$ by using the comparison test in order to avoid to solve it explicitly.
Which could be a simple function to use to prove that it's convergent?

---

EDIT: $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: $|x^{n}|e^{x}\leq 2^{n}n! e^{x/2}$.

Comment: Hello @KaviRamaMurthy how did you find it?

Comment: Using the series expansion of $e^{x/2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: we can use also function of the type $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$, where $\alpha>1$ by comparison.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy and Matteo thank you for your contribution.